# "Две большие разницы"

Tags: грамотная-речь, фразеология

Скажите, пожалуйста, насколько грамотно выражение "две большие разницы"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выражение: а) неграмотное б) устоявшееся.

Употряблялось как ирония, однако широкое его распростронение послужило причиной того, что выражение стало восприниматься как естественное и нормативное.

"Разница" - это и так различие между вещами, между двумя объектами может быть только **одна разница**. У разницы, в принципе, могут быть и другие значения, в математике, например, но сюда они уж тем более никак не подходят.

Кстати, по мнению Вики (см. "одесский язык") выражение является калькой с идиш. Хотелось бы узнать, насколько нормативным оно является там.

Answer (score 1):

Даже в "Толковом словаре живого великорусского языка" Владимира Даля, изданного в 1882 году, Вы не найдёте употребления этого малограмотного и бессмысленного выражения о двух больших "разницах". Это такая же одесская "хохма", как "четыре большие разницы".

Разница бывает только ОДНА, между чем/кем-то или чем/кем-то.

Answer (score 0):

Выражение не менее грамотно, чем "две большие комнаты", но, конечно, оно используется только в специальном, шутливом регистре речи. Это контаминация, или объединение, элементов двух семантически сходных выражений: "это два разных дела" (или "это две разные вещи") и "это большая разница".

Answer (score -1):

Думаю, выражение вполне грамотно, хотя отдает немного плеоназмом. Однако слово "большие" усиливает значение различия между какими-то понятиями